# Column check SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2012

I have a lot of views and tables connected in Microsoft SQL Server. I want to check all the useless columns I have in the native tables. Is there a way to perform an automatic check if a column in a table is used or not in other tables?

Comment: What do you mean by "perform an automatic check"??? What are you actually trying to do? And I assume by "column in a table is used or not in other tables" you are referring to foreign keys?

Comment: what do you mean by useless?  Just because it's not in other tables doesn't make it useless... i.e. PK's.

Comment: look at table dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a database diagram in SQL Server Management Studio. From here you can analyze how the tables/columns are related or not. Info [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/)
2. Do a business model analysis and see which values are used, which are deprecated and start from there.
3. If you do any changes on the database, these changes have to be projected in any code connecting to that database.

Do not remove columns in tables just by looking at a database diagram. You would destroy any object-relational mapper.